# Need to update data in database when button is clicked (PHP and HTML)

Tags: php

as part of my work I need to create a search form which brings back information from the database in a table based on what the user types in back, I have successfully managed that however I have a recommendation column on the table ("a" attribute) which has a link called "recommend this" and every time the user clicks it I want the database to update by adding +1. Thing is I don't really know how to get around doing it. I'm assuming it will have to be an if statement in php which checks if the link was pressed and if it is it will update the database.

If anyone has an idea of how I can get around solving this task then any help would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Use an ajax request to trigger PHP to add to the database, then you can also use use js to add a +1 to the dom without having to refresh.

E.g.

In js:

```
request = $.ajax({
            url: '/recommend',
            type: 'post',
            data: <a_value_or_id_to_update>
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on success
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            // Log a message to the console
            console.log("Hooray, it worked!");

            // Add +1 to the DOM element

        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // Log the error to the console
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });
```

Then in recommend.php you just need to grab the id for the row to +1, something like:

```
<?php

// db connection

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $a_value_or_id_to_update = $_POST["a_value_or_id_to_update"];

    // Query to update db here

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight forward:

1. Use jQuery --- specifically .On() @ http://api.jquery.com/on/

You need to bind the link to click event like so --

```
$( ".aClass" ).on( "click", function() {
    //do stuff from Step 2
});
```

2. Next, take a look at jQuery.ajax() @ http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You will make a call to a background processor -- say `processRequest.php`

In your first file --- the one displaying the table and where you have written the `.ajax()`, you will send over the record's ID --- In the `processRequest.php` file, you will receive the ID, and then you simply update the record's count to +1